# In Excel, how to JOIN?

Tags: join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two spreadsheets where one (`beta`) contains a subset of rows of another (`alpha`). In both spreadsheets, I have a column that is a unique ID for each row. Is there a way to find `alpha JOIN beta`? I want to be able to identify each row in `alpha` that also appears in `beta`.

I'm doing this in Google spreadsheets if that helps.

Comment: So this isn't an Excel question then??

Comment: Well, it is assuming that Google spreadsheets has the same functionality as Excel. I was hoping that this issue can be solved with a regular or ArrayFormula

Comment: Well that's quite and assumption to make! By a JOIN do you just mean to have another column with values looked up from another worksheet as in Excel's `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: If Beta's rows are a subset of Alpha's then to identify each row in Alpha that also appears in Beta - look in Beta... What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment on El Ronnoco's answer, I'm assuming you just want a column of 1s and 0s indicating whether the item in `alpha` appears in `beta`.  To do this all you need is the COUNTIF function.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(beta, alpha item)>0,1,0)
```

Comment: That worked! I didn't know `COUNTIF` could be used that way! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can do a `VLOOKUP` just the same way as you can in Excel...

[Take a look at this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsHj9SC0qi3odHVicnVSQm93cTZoQjlESGNvbkU3enc)

As I say in the comments - if `Beta`'s rows are a subset of `Alpha`'s rows then to "identify each row in `alpha` that also appears in `beta`" - you just need to look at `Beta` - because all `Beta` rows will necessarily also be in `Alpha`.

However I suspect you need some information from `Alpha` which is not in `Beta` - which is what this example shows.

[Update : As per Excellll's answer](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsHj9SC0qi3odHVicnVSQm93cTZoQjlESGNvbkU3enc)

Comment: Let me rephrase what I'm saying: In `alpha`, I want to identify if a row appears in `beta`. In other words, for each row in `alpha`, look through every row in `beta` and see if its there. If so, insert `1`, otherwise `0`

Answer (score 0):

I also propose `LookUp` and his variants or `Match` to solve, as in the following example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;[BetaBook.xls]BetaSheet!$A$1:$A$3;0));0;1)
```

I use match to search in the element of the Alpha List (A1) Appears in the Beta List (A1 to A3) in the Beta Sheet in the Beta Book (**I have both books open at the moment**), this yield the position of the element in the beta List or a #N/A error, this serves as input to `ISERROR` and `IF` to define the result 0 ( isn´t in the list) or 1 ( is in the list).

Regards